# Magento - Delete Product Type

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

When we create a new product, choose the type of product and attribute group. /
I need to delete the standard types of products Magento, leaving only the Virtual Product.
I want to delete Simple Product, Product Download, configurable product.

Anyone know how I do?

Comment: It's not straightforward. How strong a Magento developer are you?

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::getOptionArray() as

```
static public function getOptionArray()
{
    $options = array();
    foreach(self::getTypes() as $typeId=>$type) {
        if($typeId == 'virtual'):
            $options[$typeId] = Mage::helper('catalog')->__($type['label']);
        endif;
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: This worked fine for me! Thanks! But i used constant like TYPE_SIMPLE instead of "simple" for example.